# scrolling division up and another division to be fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll, slide

I'm trying to slide up the first division and make the second division visible after scrolling up. What I want is the red division to be fixed while I scroll up the green division. I'm trying to solve this from a long time but I'm not able to. Can someone please help me with this?

```css
 #pagebody{
 color:white;
background-color:red;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 
 
  
 }
#header{
color:white;
    background-color:green;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pagebody">Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!</div>
```

Comment: Right now, as I can see in snippet, Green is fixed and Red is moving up on scroll, Do you need reverse of the same?

Comment: yeah @Aman i want red to be fixed and green to scroll up. when you scroll green up red should be fixed and it should come after you scroll green up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#pagebody{
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
}

#header{
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-bottom: 100vw; // You need to add some space so that green panel should go up on scroll.
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pagebody">Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!<br>
Lato is a sanserif type­face fam­ily designed in the Sum­mer 2010 by Warsaw-​​based designer Łukasz Dziedzic (“Lato” means “Sum­mer” in Pol­ish). In Decem­ber 2010 the Lato fam­ily was pub­lished under the open-​​source Open Font License by his foundry tyPoland, with sup­port from Google.

In 2013 – 2014, the fam­ily was greatly extended to cover 3000+ glyphs per style. The Lato 2.010 fam­ily now sup­ports 100+ Latin-​​based lan­guages, 50+ Cyrillic-​​based lan­guages as well as Greek and IPA pho­net­ics. In the process, the met­rics and kern­ing of the fam­ily have been revised and four addi­tional weights were created.
Sup­port fur­ther devel­op­ment of Lato through a donation!</div>
```

As right now you have two section only and red one is in fixed position, so Green will cover body and to make green go up, you need to add some space in body to scroll green up. Right now I have added enough margin for scrolling.